# Partial Compression of an XML file

Tags: python, xml, gzip

I have an XML file as follows:

```
<data>
    <country name="USA">
        <rank>1</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank>4</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
    </country>
    <country name="USA">
        <rank>68</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
        <description test="1"> name="Colombia" direction="E" </description>
    </country>
</data>*
```

I wish to compress the children of the node with attribute name="USA". I am aware I can compress the entire file using the gzip package in python but not sure how to compress a part of the file(if possible)? Any leads for doing this ?